# Find distinct values based upon multiple columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of sales with (to keep the example simple) 3 columns

```
NAME -- STATE -- COUNTRY
```

It's easy to find how many sales. (sum all the lines)
I can find out how many customers I have but how about finding out how many customers from a particular state (and country)

```
NAME -- STATE -- COUNTRY
p1----- CA------ USA
p2----- CA------ USA
p1----- CA------ USA
p1----- CA------ USA
p3----- NY------ USA
p3----- NY------ USA
```

The above example would give 2 unique customers from  CA and 1 unique customer from NY and 3 from the USA

**EDIT:**

The desired result from the above table would be

```
STATE - UNIQUE CUSTOMERS 
CA ----  2
NY ----  1

COUNTRY - UNIQUE CUSTOMERS
USA ---- 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data have headers in row 1 of columns A, B, and C, follow these directions.

In cell F1 enter STATE.

In cell G1 enter COUNT.

In cell F2 enter this array-formula (must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),MATCH(0,COUNTIF(F$1:F1,B$2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))),)),"")
```

In cell G2 enter this regular formula (confirmed with Enter):

```
=IF(LEN(F2),COUNTIF(B2:B13,F2),"")
```

Select `F2:G2` and copy.

Now select `F3:F51` and paste.

***UPDATE***

The nature of the question changed. The first formula is exactly the same as before. It gets the distinct states in the source data and culls them so they display with no blanks.

The second formula is now different. It needs to count the number of distinct customers in each state, and it is now an array formula confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>).

```
=IF(LEN(F2),SUM(IF(F2=$B$2:$B$50,1/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$50,F2,$A$2:$A$50,$A$2:$A$50)),)),"")
```

Comment: I'm reviewing this I don't see how this works. How does this reference column A (the names)?  Secondly why the "must be confirmed with Control-Alt-Delete? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Happy to answer your questions, but first have you tried it by following the directions?

Comment: Sorry, that should be Control-Shift-Enter.

Comment: I'm trying. Failing. But trying. :-)

Comment: I followed the directions to a "t". But I'm missing something. I've looked up control-shift-enter as for making arrays. Interesting. But I'm getting a negative. (Example: if I put in "nope" at the end ... ),"") I get nope in the cells.

Comment: @Mayo No worries. Here is a workbook I just put together for you with your sample data. It has this answer implemented. Here is the [file](http:///www.excelhero.com/samples/distinct_values_count_excelhero.xlsx)

Comment: Thx.  I didn't explain myself properly. In the example you made There should be 2 unique customers from california and 1 from ny.  I see where I went wrong my paste did not include the array { }. I have to work on that aspect.

Comment: @Mayo No worries. Can you please tell me what the output SHOULD look like for your sample data. I can then update my answer and sample workbook.

Comment: @Mayo Yep. That's a completely different problem. But I have it sorted and here is the new [workbook file](http:///www.excelhero.com/samples/distinct_values_count2_excelhero.xlsx)

Answer (score 1):

This formula (entered as an array formula CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER) will count the number of occurrences of a Name in MyState

```
=COUNTIFS(Names,Names,States,MyState)
```

So if MyState="CA" this would return {3;1;3;3;0;0}

To get the number of names in CA you can sum the reciprocals of this array, EXCEPT taking the reciprocal of zero is invalid/infinite. So wrap the formula above in a test for zero: if it's zero, output zero, otherwise take the reciprocal (one of the rare situations where you get to set infinity equal to zero!):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Names,Names,States,MyState)=0,0,1/COUNTIFS(Names,Names,States,MyState))
```

(Still an array formula.)

For CA this will return {0.333333;1;0.333333;0.333333;0;0}

The final step is to sum with the array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIFS(Names,Names,States,MyState)=0,0,1/COUNTIFS(Names,Names,States,MyState)))
```

It's possible that this could return say 2.99999... instead of 3 due to rounding errors. If that's a problem you can fix it by wrapping it with the ROUND function or setting the display format zero decimal places.

It should be straightforward to modify this to count by country. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question also has an 'google-spreadsheets' tag, this would be my suggested formula to use in a google spreadsheet:

For the state counts:

```
=query(unique(ArrayFormula({A2:A&B2:B, A2:C})), "select Col3, count(Col1) where Col3 <> '' group by Col3 label count(Col1)''",0)
```

And for the country counts:

```
=query(unique(ArrayFormula({A2:A&B2:B&C2:C, C2:C})), "select Col2, count(Col1) where Col2 <> '' group by Col2 label count(Col1)''",0)
```

Also see [this example spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GadOivkxnJ_WxAZ3EsLGdX9WQqxjYaHwD1KhConPICk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: don't have access to google at work. Will look later on tonight,

Comment: I've set the sharing to 'public' so you should be able to see it now.

Answer (score -1):

Easy with a PivotTable in Excel 2013:

[image: SO32302815 first example]

Also easy with Google Spreadsheets:

[image: SO32302815 second example]

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not interested in using a pivot table. This will be used on google sheets as well.